# Synchronise Git Reposiptory

Tags: git

I am not sure whether this is achievable or not. I have tried to research but could not find the answer.

Basically, I am planning to clone from an existing Git repository and I want this Git repository to be synchronised all the time. This will be on 1 machine (Ubuntu).

Now, I want to pull changes from this Ubuntu machine to my local desktop machine. Make changes and push back to the Ununtu machine.

Next the Ununtu machine, should push changes that were made to the original Git repository.

Is this achievable and if yes how can this be done? Otherwise, what are the alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: Set `remote` to the ubuntu machine's git repo and set up a `post-reveive` server side git [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on ubuntu to automatically push changes to the original repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy peasy. Just setup a server side hook on Ubuntu machine to repush after it receives a push (see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks post-receive) (or run a periodic cron job to push) or on your machine, push to both.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will I need to setup a mirror in order to achieve this fully? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement to make code private while  sharing with colleague over git.  What you can do is create  onedrive account and setup same in both Ubuntu and your main repo server.  Now you can host your repo in that folder. So one drive will always sync your repo and this side you can always have updated code on Ubuntu from where u can clone to other machine , make changes and push back to Ubuntu. Now it will be automatically sync with main git repo server.  So either  party need to make sure that it sync onedrive folder before pull or push code from ubuntu or main reason repo.